# remove *.tar.gz file more than 3 years

Tags: linux

let say in /data/in contains common folders, files and archive files with extension .tar.gz

how to remove those .tar.gz only which older than 3 yrs without affecting other common folders and files?

I have a problem how to only grep *.tar.gz only in order to use find command.

Comment: What commands have you tried? The `find` command can easily do what you suggest. Just read its man page.

Answer (score 2):

This will search in `/data/in` and find files (`-type f`) with the name ending in `.tar.gz` which are older (`-not -newer`) then the timestamp on the file `/tmp/end`:

```
touch --date "2011-09-03" /tmp/end # Specify a specific date from 3+ years ago
find /data/in -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -not -newer /tmp/end
```

You can also use the flags `-mtime N` to [search for files older then the last N days](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/), but sometimes it's easier to simply specify a date instead of calculating the number of days over 3 and some-odd days.

Inspiration from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osxfind-files-by-date/

Comment: Also see [[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/calculate-the-date-from-1125-days-ago-on-non-gnu-systems]]